# x-editable: How to update the post URL itself with field values?

Tags: jquery, ajax, x-editable, bootstrap-table

The API I'm attempting to post to is constructed as follows: `/device/invoiceNumber/{invoiceNumber}/{portableUnitId}`

where the values in brackets must be replaced with dynamically added values from the bootstrap-table. I can generate the custom URL in another function, but what I have here isn't working:

`$(this).data('url', postInvNumUrl);`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, you have to update the option on `editable` itself:

```
// This is where the magic happens
$(this).editable('option', 'url', postInvNumUrl);

// Not sure if this is needed anymore 
$(this).data('url', postInvNumUrl);
```